# Check for save (if @model.save) using .map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I check if the model is saved when using the Ruby .map method?  My code is as follows:

```
@subscription = feed.map { |subscribe| Subscription.create(dashboard_id: dashboard, category_id: category, feed_id: subscribe) }

respond_to do |format|
  if @subscription.save
    format.html { redirect_to subscriptions_path, notice: 'Subscription was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @subscription }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @subscription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

The line `if @subscription.save` throws an error `undefined method`save' for #`.

I understand why this is, but how do I fix this?  I still want to check for save before redirecting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns an array, so `@subscription` would be an array of `Subscription` objects, since you're using `create`.

You could do something like:

`@subscription.any?(&:blank?)` to see if there are any `nil`, `false`, or `""` elements in the array...

Or (worse, because it would be another database call for each record), you could do:

`@subscription.map(&:save).flatten.any?(&:blank)` to re-save all elements in the array and ensure all returned `true`.

I think the former is the best approach... So your code would look like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  unless @subscription.any?(&:blank?)
    format.html { redirect_to subscriptions_path, notice: 'Subscription was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @subscription.map(&:errors).flatten, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: Great, thanks - but should it be the opposite way around? If @subscription.any are blank?, then render new, and if not, then render success?

Comment: I won't fix this now because I'm on my phone, but you'll need to adjust `@subscription.errors` as well.

Comment: Okay, I've adjusted it.  It may need some tweaking to render correctly.